# There exists a real number $x$ such that if $x^2 ≥0$ then $ x=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I have to prove: There exists a real number $x$ such that if $x^2 ≥0$ then $x=0$.

I have no idea what should I proceed.

I tried to come up with the contrapositive, and it doesn't help.

I have this so far (and I am sure this is not valid):

> Suppose $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$. Thus we can also say that  $x^2 ∈\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Set $x^2 =0$, which is clearly $≥0$.
>
> Hence, $x=0$ □

I am right, this is the question: [image]

Comment: Are you sure this is the question? You can choose $x = 0$, because then your consequent is always true. If $Q$ is true, then $P \implies Q$ is as well.

Comment: yeahh thats why I'm super confused. I asked my teacher, and he said to me that the statement is perfectly fine.

Comment: Since $x^2\ge0, \forall x\in\mathbb R,$ the only such $x$ is $0.$

Comment: The question is kinda confusing. the thing that made me confused is that when i set x=0, I ended up with the conclusion, and it's weird

Comment: @awllower sorry I don't get what you mean. Can you explain to me why 0 is the only possible value of x?

Comment: $x^2\ge0\implies x=0$ but $x^2\ge0$ always holds?

Comment: I have no idea what to write for the proof. I get the whole picture, but I don't know where to start

Comment: $0=0$ is true, so $0^2\geq 0 \implies 0=0$ is true, so $\exists x(x^2\geq 0\implies x=0)$.

Comment: @Aaron If you were asked to prove that there exists a real number $x$ such that $x > 5$, how would you approach that problem?

Comment: @ChrisCulter Can I just consider $x= 6$ and hence its true since $6>5$ ?

Comment: @Aaron Yep! You just have to give a single example, and you're done. Existence is proven. Now for your original question, all you have to do is propose a specific number $x$ that makes the statement "if $x^2\geq0$ then $x=0$" true.

Comment: @ChrisCulter but, is it just weird if you propose, for instance $x=0$, at the beginning, and then getting $x=0$ back at the end?

Comment: Im just wondering if I rephrase the statement to be: There exists a real number $x$ such that $x^2>0$ or $x=0$. Is it just trivial? I mean like its just self-explanatory -- $x=0$ certainly $∈ℝ$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the problem feels strange because there isn't much to prove. It might help to introduce extra notation to disambiguate between the roles of the different utterances of the equation $x=0$. For example:

> Let $p(x)$ be the statement that $x^2\geq 0$, and let $q(x)$ be the statement that $x=0$. We are asked to prove the existence of $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $p(x)\implies q(x)$. It suffices that $0\in \mathbb R$; we have $q(0)$ by construction, and so $p(0)\implies q(0)$.

Yes, the question is trivial, which is probably the point. The author is probably asking you to tackle this problem to see if you can slow down, step back, and figure out exactly what needs to be done. The inequality $x^2\geq0$ is bait for a trap; it's trying to tempt you into entering Automatic Equation-Solving Mode, and that mode of thinking doesn't help here.

Answer (score 2):

$0\in\mathbb R$ and $0=0$ is true. So $0^2\geq 0 \implies 0=0$ is true, so $\exists x\in\mathbb R(x^2\geq 0\implies x=0)$.

Comment: oh cool! by the way, is my proof above considered valid? I'm just wondering.

Comment: Your proof is not valid - you can't "set $x^2=0$."

Comment: Im just wondering if I rephrase the statement to be: There exists a real number $x$ such that $x^2>0$ or $x=0$. Is it just trivial? I mean like its just self-explanatory -- $x=0$ certainly $∈ℝ$

Comment: $x^2\geq 0$ has no bearing on this question, really. You could replace literally any statement $Q(x)$ and get a true statement: $\exists x(Q(x)\implies x=0)$ and it is still true. Heck, $Q(x)$ can be patently false, like $x+1<x$.

Comment: I think you are missing how silly the statement we are proving is.

Answer (score 1):

For any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $x^2 \geq 0$.  So the statement
$$ \exists x \in \mathbb{R} : (x^2 \geq 0 \implies x=0)$$

is equivalent to
$$ \exists x: x=0$$

Comment: umm is that because $x=0$ is always true and hence, you can ignore the hypothesis?

Comment: @Aaron See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your question once. But if it is the same then the solution is $x$ belongs to $[0,\infty ) $ which says that x can also be zero. But it is not true that x should only be zero.

Comment: The statement is quite clear: $\exists x(x^2\geq 0\implies x=0)$. It's also true, although silly, statement.

Comment: I have edited the post, and it seems like the question is as it is

Comment: Your proof is not valid - you can't "set $x^2=0$."

Comment: Yes you are right @Aaron but what  i want to convey  is that x=0 is not the only possible solution but it belongs to $[0,\ infty )$.

Comment: Solution to what, @user291957? The statement $x^2\geq 0\implies x=0$ is only true for $x=0$.